# Hide div depending on variable response

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to build a tube status site, the idea is to display the status of each tube line (good service, minor delays etc)

At first I wanted to display all, and to colour code the responses, so everything but "good service" would be red text.

Instead what I'd like to do is hide the entire div if it is a good service. Meaning you'd only see the tube lines that don't have a response of "Good Service"

I have the same code for each tube line, but just showing 1 example below

Here is the javascript

```
$.getJSON ('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/central/Status? 
detail=false&app_id=APIID&app_key=APIKEY', 
function(data) { console.log(data);

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
console.log(value);

var statuscentral = value.lineStatuses[0].statusSeverityDescription;
console.log(statuscentral);

$('.statuscentral').text(statuscentral);

if (statuscentral != "Good Service") {
tube.classList.add("noShow");
}
});
});
```

Not sure if it helpful to include, but here is the html

```
<div class="tube">
<span class="central"></span>
<h2 class="tube-title">Central</h2>
<h3 class="statuscentral"></h3>
</div>
```

And is the css

```
/* create 3 equal columns that floats next to each other */
.tube {
float: left;
width: 33%;
padding-bottom: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}

/* styles for tube span */
.central {
background-color: #ED462F;
}

/* hides div */
.noShow {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a CSS class that hides the divs.

```
.noShow{display: none;}
```

And then you can use the classList.add function to give the div that class based on your logic

```
if(statuscentral != "Good Service"){
tube.classList.add("noShow");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I've edited my code above to show what I did

Comment: the part that says "tube.classList.add the "tube" probably isn't correct.That's my bad, I threw some psuedocode in there and should have mentioned it. It will need to be whatever element you are working with in the DOM.

Comment: Ah thanks Sean. I'm very new to javascript and API's, would I instead change it from "tube" to lineStatuses[0].statusSeverityDescription.classList.add("noShow"); I did try and it still didn't seem to work

Comment: I fear I may have led you down the wrong path here. I suppose you're pulling data from a json and then determining what to do with it. My solution was if the divs were already created and you wanted to get rid of them. Your solution would be more along the lines of

if(statuscentral = "Good Service"){
      do some stuff to create the div
}else{
      do nothing
}